# spring boot dynamic response type

Tags: ajax, spring-boot, exceptionhandler, controller-advice

I am using **@ControllerAdvice** to do exception handling globally. but I want to return the exception in **Json** format if the request is **ajax(xhr)** and if it's not I want to show my exception as **html**.

so the response type is dynamic. it might be html or json. And I am using **thymleaf** to generate my html pages.

how can I do that in spring boot?

```
    @ResponseBody
    @ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
    public ModelAndView handle(Exception exception, WebRequest request) {
        this.logException(exception, request);
        var model = getErrorPageModel(exception);
        return new ModelAndView("exception", model, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Comment: You want [content negotiation](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-content-negotiation-json-xml). Use the `Accept` header in your requests to tell Spring you want `application/json` responses

Comment: I had to change all the ajax requests as you mentioned. Thanks. I taught there is a standard measure to separate ajax requests. @Phil

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Step 1: Determine which type of view you want

From the `WebRequest`, you have to retrieve the necessary information to either return JSON or HTML. One possible way of doing so is by parsing the `Accept` header:

```java
List<MediaType> mediaTypes = MediaType.parseMediaTypes(request.getHeader("Accept"));
if (mediaTypes.contains(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)) {
   // TODO: Implement HTML view
} else {
    // TODO: Implement JSON view
}
```

A better alternative is to use Spring's [`ContentNegotiationManager`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/accept/ContentNegotiationManager.html) by autowiring it into your controller advice:

```java
// TODO: Autowire a bean of `ContentNegotiationManager` into your ControllerAdvice class
List<MediaType> mediaTypes = contentNegotiationManager.resolveMediaTypes(request);
if (mediaTypes.contains(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)) {
   // TODO: Implement HTML view
} else {
    // TODO: Implement JSON view
}
```

By default, Spring Boot's `ContentNegotiationManager` will do exactly the same as the original code, but this can be [extended with other strategies](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/web/webmvc/mvc-servlet/viewresolver.html#mvc-multiple-representations).

Be aware that the `resolveMediaTypes()` method requires a `NativeWebRequest`. So you have to change the type of the `request` parameter.

#### Step 2: Implement the model + view

Now what you have to do is implement the model and view for both the HTML and JSON view.

For the HTML view, you can use a Thymeleaf template, for example `error.html`:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<body>
<p><strong>Error:</strong> <span th:text="${message}"></span></p>
</body>
```

After that, you can return the following `ModelAndView` from your exception handler:

```java
return new ModelAndView("error", Map.of("message", ex.getMessage()));
```

For the JSON part, you can use the `MappingJackson2JsonView` view class:

```java
// TODO: Autowire a bean of `ObjectMapper` into your ControllerAdvice class
return new ModelAndView(new MappingJackson2JsonView(objectMapper), Map.of("message", ex.getMessage()));
```

This requires an `ObjectMapper`, which you can autowire into your controller advice.

Everything combined you get:

```java
@ExceptionHandler(Exception.class)
public ModelAndView handleException(Exception ex, NativeWebRequest request) throws HttpMediaTypeNotAcceptableException {
    List<MediaType> mediaTypes = contentNegotiationManager.resolveMediaTypes(request);
    Map<String, String> model = Map.of("message", ex.getMessage());
    if (mediaTypes.contains(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)) {
        return new ModelAndView("error", model);
    } else {
        return new ModelAndView(new MappingJackson2JsonView(objectMapper), model);
    }
}
```

> **Note**: In this example I'm assuming that if the `Accept` header contains `text/html` you want to return the HTML view and in every other case you want to return the JSON view. You can change this logic to whatever you want.

Comment: Thanks for the information and the last peace of code which was the exact one I was looking for.